# Is there an easy way to display the profile image from graph api in a react application

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking for an easy way to display the image response from graph api into the react application. Something like this https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/05/how-to-get-and-display-the-user-photo-with-graph-sdk-for-net-in-a-wpf-application/

When I try I get this from the api, not sure what format the response is in  and how to convert and show it as image?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you get a response from the API yet? If so, what does it look like? If not [how about checking out the docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/react)

Comment: @Taxel , I updated the question with the response I get from the api, Is there a way how we can convert the response I got and show as image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MS [Graph Docs - Using the binary data of the requested photo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#using-the-binary-data-of-the-requested-photo) has some helpful note.

Here is a sample component pulled from the docs. Note am using Axios to fetch the photo using  responseType: 'blob' config and render it when I have it.

I could not get it to work without that config.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios'

function App() {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value', {
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ...' },
      responseType: 'blob'
    }).then(o => {
      const url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      const blobUrl = url.createObjectURL(o.data);
      setImageUrl(blobUrl)
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {imageUrl && <img alt='my-user-avatar' src={imageUrl} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

FYI, you may also be interested in using [MS Graph UI Toolkit for Reactjs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/use-toolkit-with-react) as you seem to be rendering user profile card.

Comment: Can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69188265/how-to-fetch-ms-graph-user-photo-as-a-blob-url-and-store-them-in-the-application,  I need to store this blob for later use in DB? How to do it?

Comment: For this type of storage you could convert to base 64 and store or use binary storage if your database engine supports that. A better solution would be to use blob storage like [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction) which you can call using REST. Do your proper research before settling on a solution that fits your scenario.

Comment: i need some help with this function please

Comment: None of these work for img src:  1) `btoa(results.data)`, I get `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range`. 2) `btoa(encodeURIComponent(results.data))`, displays broken image icon. 3) `URL.createObjectURL(results.data)`, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed`. 4) Binary data only, the page is filled with 'diamond' and random characters.

Answer (score 4):

I tried different approaches and finally this worked for me.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const getPhoto = async () => {
      const graphEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value";

      const response = await axios(graphEndpoint, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("accesstoken")}` },
        responseType: "arraybuffer"
      });
      const avatar = Buffer.from(response.data, "binary").toString("base64");

      setPhotoData("data:image/jpeg;base64, " + avatar);
    };

    getPhoto();
  }, []);
```

Comment: How did you set the accessToken to session storage?

Comment: can you help me with your answer please ?

Comment: this just returns broken image icon for me when i try and use it as the image source.

Answer (score 1):

I've got mine working without importing a new library for the api request. Hope the below helps anyone that's stuck.

My downfall was not specifying the dimensions for the image. If you don't do this it won't render.

```
useEffect(() => {
    GetProfilePicture()
}, [])

const [image, setImage] = useState()

const [isOk, setResponse] = useState()

const GetProfilePicture = async () => {

    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = 'Bearer ${props.token}';

    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
    headers.append("Content-type", 'image/jpeg');

    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers,
    };

    await fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value", options)
    .then(response => {

        response.blob().then((data) => {
            const reader = new FileReader()
        
        reader.readAsDataURL(data)

        reader.onload = () => {
            const base64data = reader.result;
            
            setImage(base64data)
            setResponse(response.ok)
            
            }
        })
    })
} 

const ProfilePic = () => {
    if (isOk != false) {
        return (
            <Image style={{height: 90, width: 90}} key={image} source={{uri: image}}></Image>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <Fragment></Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```