# How to fetch MS graph user photo as a blob url and store them in the application db as blob url

Tags: reactjs, image, microsoft-graph-api, blob, binary-data

I tried using the responseType as blob but it returns the binary data. I can leverage react frameworks to do any extra operations needed to accomplish it.

[image]

Below is what I tried,

Converted the binary to blob, but this blob cannot be stored in the DB or use it later as it has "localhost" url.

[image]